# How to tell when user selects "Open in Chrome" from menu

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm trying to determine when the user opens a Chrome Custom Tab in Chrome (the "Open in Chrome" option from the menu).

My navigation callback returns an event code of 6, which is the same code returned when the user closes a Custom Tab. Is there a way to differentiate between whether the user has closed the Custom Tab or opened it in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation code 6 means that CustomTabs Activity is not visible any more for either user has navigated back to the activity that started the CustomTabs intent or another activity, in this case Chrome has been started, has taken place.

When the user navigates from CustomTabs activity to Chrome you get navigation code 6, when back button is hit, another event is sent with code 5 (tab visible again). In this case you are the CustomActivity is still visible, previous activity was finished, the activity that started the intent is still paused.

Starting CustomTabs for activity might solve your case when you have navigation code 6 and `onActivityResult()` method called on the activity that started the session.

```
public void openUrlForResult(String url, int requestCode){
    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = buildCustomTabIntent(mCustomTabSession);
    customTabsIntent.intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    mContext.startActivityForResult(customTabsIntent.intent, requestCode);
}
```